# How do I loop through a string and store it into an array in NASM?

Tags: arrays, nasm

(total newbie to NASM struggling to learn)

I've put the 1st command line argument into register eax. It can be a string between 1-20 lowercase characters.

I now want to loop through this string, copying one character at a time into a byte array A in the program's memory and storing the length of the string N in memory too. At this point in the program I've checked that the string is a legal input and is fine length-wise and case-wise.

This is a rough structure (?) that doesn't seem to be working:

```
section .bss                ; uninitialized data
   N resd 1                 ; length of string
   A resb 1                 ; byte array A

section .text
   asm_main:
   // legal input checking code

   mov edx, 0          

   loop2:
      mov al, [eax+edx]
      mov [A+edx],al
      inc edx
      cmp al, 0
      jz done_loop2
      jmp loop2

   done_loop2:
      mov [N], edx
      call print_int
      mov eax, A
      call print_string

    // code for jumps to errors and end of main
```

(I'm only printing the size and string to check if the loops works correctly)
I'm getting unexpected outputs: for eg
 input "hello" gives me
 -6193920
 hxETmcxbt=Se6o=Eaco/oa

Any help would be super appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you an example:

```
    global asm_main

SECTION .data
        global x
        mystring: db "stackoverflow",0
        mystringl: equ $-mystring
        array: TIMES mystringl dd 0
SECTION .text

asm_main:
        enter 0,0
        pusha
        mov ecx, 0                      ; counter

looper:
        cmp byte[mystring+ecx], 0x0     ; check for end of string
        je exit

        mov eax, 0                      ; empty eax
        mov al, byte[mystring+ecx]      ; move string position into al
        mov byte[array+ecx], al         ; write into memory

        push eax
        mov eax, 0
        mov al, byte[array+ecx]
        call print_char
        call print_nl
        pop eax

        add ecx, 1
        jmp looper

exit:
```

If you need any help, feel free to message me.

Comment: This helped a lot! I got it to work. Thank you. So I need to empty out eax before I save something new in it? Why do you empty it then push it on the stack, then pop it in the end?

Comment: Calling print_char or print method uses EAX register to pass the argument

Comment: How's the project going?